# Equivalent of subselect from related table?

Tags: sql, join, axapta, x++, subquery

I'm trying to write the equivalent of the following SQL query in Axapta/X++, using the `Query`/`QueryRun`/etc. system:

```
SELECT FieldA,
       (SELECT SUM(FieldB) FROM TableB X WHERE X.FieldA = TableA.FieldA),
       (SELECT SUM(FieldB) FROM TableB Y WHERE Y.FieldA = TableA.FieldA),
       (SELECT SUM(FieldB) FROM TableB Z WHERE Z.FieldA = TableA.FieldA)
    FROM TableA
```

However, as far as I know, Axapta does not support subselect fields, so I can't write it directly as-is.

Is there some little-known feature or clever way to write this query other than using the database directly?

(I don't want to iterate over `TableA` and run the subqueries separately because that's how my report works now and it's too slow).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In this case I would [use the display method modifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa595058.aspx) on TableA.
Below is some pseudo-code, applied as a TableA buffer method.

```
display Amount getX()
{
    TableB tableB;
    ;
    select sum(FieldB) from tableB where tableB.FieldA == this.FieldA)
    return tableB.FieldB; 
}
```

As you can imagine, this approach is more costly than your SQL approach, so some [datasource caching(scroll to bottom)](http://www.axaptapedia.com/index.php?title=Display_method) can help.
Also, no sorting or filtering is possible on display methods.

Comment: If you're going this route, you should probably use a `cacheAddMethod` for performance.  See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa893273(v=ax.50).aspx